# ¿Cómo se usa una condición where para varios campos los cuales pueden o no tener datos SQL Server?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Primeramente disculpas si no soy claro.

Estoy realizando búsquedas sobre una tabla, cuando el usuario tiene un criterio de búsqueda utilizo la condición where y where campo = "criterioDeBusqueda", eso funciona correcto.

Pero al no ingresar un dato, no quiero discriminar datos (sería algo como where campo = true, no funciona), y mostrar todos, sin restricción.

El problema surge cuando este misma lógica utilizo para varios campos, quiero realizarlo todo en una consulta (si es posible).

Como ven hay veces que se consulta una determinada Zona pero otras veces no se ingresa una zona determinada y quiero mostrarlas todas, sin restricción

La consulta que uso con todos los join les dejo (está bastante incompleta).

O debo usar otra cosa en lugar del where.

Gracias de antemano.

```
using (DBPrototipoSeguridadEntities mde = new DBPrototipoSeguridadEntities())
                {
                    //Consulta que devuelve los valores de las tablas Evento y TipoEvento
                    var consultaListaEventos = from evento in mde.Evento
                                               join eventoPorZonas in mde.EventoPorZonas
                                               on evento.idEvento equals eventoPorZonas.fkidEvento

                                               join zona in mde.ZonaSistemaAlarma
                                               on eventoPorZonas.fkidZona equals zona.idZona

                                               join tipoEvento in mde.TipoEvento
                                               on evento.fkidTipoEvento equals tipoEvento.idTipoEvento

                                               join estadoEvento in mde.EstadoEvento
                                               on evento.fkidEstadoEvento equals estadoEvento.idEstadoEvento

                                               join cliente in mde.Cliente
                                               on evento.fkidCliente equals cliente.idCliente

                                               join persona in mde.Persona
                                               on evento.fkidPersona equals persona.idPersona

                                               join usuarioSupervisor in mde.Usuario
                                               on evento.fkidUsuarioSupervisor equals usuarioSupervisor.idUsuario

                                               join usuarioOperador in mde.Usuario
                                               on evento.fkidUsuarioOperador equals usuarioOperador.idUsuario

                                               //where estadoEvento.idEstadoEvento == estadoEventoLocal

                                               where cliente.numeroCuenta == cuentaCliente || estadoEvento.idEstadoEvento == estadoEventoLocal || estadoEvento.idEstadoEvento == true
                                               select new
                                               {
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta era usar condicionales después de realizar la consulta.

```
                    //Condicional de consulta para la cuenta cliente. Si existe una criterio se busca de lo contrario se muestra todos
                    if (cuentaCliente != " ")
                    {
                        consultaListaEventos = consultaListaEventos.Where(p => p.numeroCuenta == cuentaCliente);
                    }
```